# How can I integrate on-premises GitHub Enterprise into Jira Cloud if only connections from GitHub Enterprise to Jira are allowed?

Tags: github, jira, github-enterprise

### Infrastructure:

- Jira Cloud (since Atlassian is sadly killing their on-premises variant Jira Server)
- GitHub Enterprise (on-premises)

### Goals:

- See pull requests, their status and commits in Jira
- Navigate to the pull requests and commits using links to internal URLs
- **No connections into our network from outside**

Do you know any solutions? Either GitHub Enterprise would need to update Jira or an on-premises third-party tool would need to connect to both.

Thank you very much in advance for your input!